# Set cookie after closing div

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my html:

```
 <span class="boxclose" id='close'>X</span>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('close').onclick = function(){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
        .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
    };
};
</script>
```

All works, but i have no idea how i would update the script to set a cookie to remember, once it has been closed. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Use `localStorage` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Is localstorate and cookie are same things?

Comment: Pretty much the same, I prefer to use localStorage though

Comment: Cookies and localStorage aren't remotely the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Saving and reading cookies

If you want to read and save cookies the easy way you can use the two functions below from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). If the close element gets clicked I create a cookie named "closed" for which I set the value to "True". On the page load the cookie "closed" just gets checked if it was indeed already clicked.

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

window.onload = function() {
  if (getCookie("closed") == "True") {
    document.getElementById('close').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('close').parentNode.parentNode);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('close').onclick = function() {
      setCookie("closed", "True", 42);
      this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
      return false;
    };
  }
};
```

For more information about cookies [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

---

### Saving inside and reading from the localStorage

This is an example with **localStorage** which might be interesting for you since a localStorage item is almost like a cookie.

Once you click on the close element I store that it has been clicked inside the localStorage by using `localStorage.setItem("closed","True");`. To now check if the element was already  closed by the visitor on a previous visit etc. you can use `localStorage.getitem("closed")` which will return "True" (in this case) and compare it to the String "True".

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.getItem("closed") == "True") {
      document.getElementById('close').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('close').parentNode.parentNode);
    }
    document.getElementById('close').onclick = function() {
      this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
      localStorage.setItem("closed", "True");
      return false;
    };
  } else {
    alert("Your browser does not support localStorage");
  }
};
```

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/flosommerfeld/frj075x5/1) for a functioning jsfiddle.
For more information about localStorage I recommend [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I hope it does now

Comment: The question asks how to set and read a cookie. How does this answer that question?

Comment: He said any help would be appreciated and it does not look like he necessarily needs a cookie

Comment: Well, edited the answer once again